# How to handle CONSUMPTION_REQUEST notification in iOS in app purchase

Tags: ios, notifications, in-app-purchase

Per ios [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/send_consumption_information)

> The App Store uses a variety of factors to determine if a refund request is approved or denied. To help inform and improve the refund process, you can send information about a user’s consumption of an in-app purchase to the App Store when the user requests a refund. The App Store uses the consumption information you provide to inform its refund decisions.

> When a customer initiates a refund request for a consumable in-app purchase, the App Store sends a CONSUMPTION_REQUEST notification_type to your server through App Store Server Notifications. If the customer provided consent, respond by calling this API and sending the consumption data in the ConsumptionRequest to the App Store. If not, respond by calling this API and setting the customerConsented value to false in the ConsumptionRequest; don't send any other information.

Now we got a CONSUMPTION_REQUEST notification_type and the content is

```
{Environment:PROD 
 NotificationType:CONSUMPTION_REQUEST 
 Password:xxxx0b91b407f5xxxxxxxxx 
 ExpirationIntent: 
 AutoRenewAdamID: 
 AutoRenewStatus: 
 AutoRenewProductID:
 AutoRenewStatusChangeDate:{AutoRenewStatusChangeDate: AutoRenewStatusChangeDateMS: AutoRenewStatusChangeDatePST:} 
 BID:com.boundle.id
 BVRS:89 
 UnifiedReceipt:{
    Status:0 
    Environment:Production 
    LatestReceipt:MIISegYJKoZIhvcNXXXXXXXXXX 
 LatestReceiptInfo:[] 
 PendingRenewalInfo:[]
 }
}
```

It seems there is no receipt transaction id which the customer asks for a refund.

And then we try to get the receipt details through `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` with `LatestReceipt` of notification

```
{ receipt:
   { receipt_type: 'Production',
     adam_id: 125258871623,
     app_item_id: 125258871623,
     bundle_id: 'com.boundle.id',
     application_version: '89',
     download_id: null,
     version_external_identifier: 843111111,
     receipt_creation_date: '2021-07-18 04:48:20 Etc/GMT',
     receipt_creation_date_ms: '1626583700000',
     receipt_creation_date_pst: '2021-07-17 21:48:20 America/Los_Angeles',
     request_date: '2021-07-20 08:02:21 Etc/GMT',
     request_date_ms: '1626768141824',
     request_date_pst: '2021-07-20 01:02:21 America/Los_Angeles',
     original_purchase_date: '2021-07-07 00:03:57 Etc/GMT',
     original_purchase_date_ms: '1625616237000',
     original_purchase_date_pst: '2021-07-06 17:03:57 America/Los_Angeles',
     original_application_version: '87',
     in_app: [] },
  environment: 'Production',
  status: 0 }
{ receipt_type: 'Production',
  adam_id: 125258871623,
  app_item_id: 125258871623,
  bundle_id: 'com.boundle.id',
  application_version: '89',
  download_id: null,
  version_external_identifier: 843111111,
  receipt_creation_date: '2021-07-18 04:48:20 Etc/GMT',
  receipt_creation_date_ms: '1626583700000',
  receipt_creation_date_pst: '2021-07-17 21:48:20 America/Los_Angeles',
  request_date: '2021-07-20 08:02:21 Etc/GMT',
  request_date_ms: '1626768141824',
  request_date_pst: '2021-07-20 01:02:21 America/Los_Angeles',
  original_purchase_date: '2021-07-07 00:03:57 Etc/GMT',
  original_purchase_date_ms: '1625616237000',
  original_purchase_date_pst: '2021-07-06 17:03:57 America/Los_Angeles',
  original_application_version: '87',
  in_app: [] }
```

There is no refund receipt info either.

Per doc, once received CONSUMPTION_REQUEST, we should send Consumption Information through API

`PUT https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/transactions/consumption/{originalTransactionId}`

How could we get the originalTransactionId from notification?

Answer (score 1):

On my case, there is `original_transaction_id` in the top level properties of the notification payload.

Comment: After review this doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody?changes=latest_minor, the `original_transaction_id ` is added to notification recently....

Comment: I notice the type of `original_transaction_id` in the top level properties of the notification is long, whereas the the type of original_transaction_id of unified_receipt.Latest_receipt_info is string. Could you please tell me what is the real type of original_transaction_id in the top level?